# [ROS2][rclpy] how to set parameter hosted by another Node via service

Tags: ros, ros2, call-service, rclpy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a solution to set the Parameter which is host by another node using `rclpy`.

I found there is a relavent [post](https://answers.ros.org/question/340600/how-to-get-ros2-parameter-hosted-by-another-node/), but in `rclcpp`.

While, I tried below. But the error occurred. Any idea how I can fix it? Thank you very much!

```
import time

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import rclpy.qos as qos

from rclpy.parameter import Parameter
# from rcl_interfaces.msg import Parameter
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterValue
from rcl_interfaces.srv import SetParameters, GetParameters, ListParameters
from rcl_interfaces.msg import ParameterDescriptor, ParameterValue


class MinimalClientAsync(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('my_node')

        self.cli = self.create_client(SetParameters, '/another_node/set_parameters')
        while not self.cli.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=1.0):
            self.get_logger().info('service not available, waiting again...')
        self.req = SetParameters.Request()

    def send_request(self):
        self.req.parameters = [Parameter(name='parameter_1', value=13)]
        self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_client = MinimalClientAsync()
    minimal_client.send_request()

    while rclpy.ok():
        rclpy.spin_once(minimal_client)
        if minimal_client.future.done():
            try:
                response = minimal_client.future.result()
            except Exception as e:
                minimal_client.get_logger().info(
                    'Service call failed %r' % (e,))
            break

    minimal_client.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error is:

```
  File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rcl_interfaces/srv/_set_parameters.py", line 138, in parameters
    "The 'parameters' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'Parameter'"
AssertionError: The 'parameters' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'Parameter'
```

I also tried to use `rcl_interfaces.msg.Parameter` instead of `rclpy.parameter.Parameter` so it won't failed at `rcl_interfaces/srv/_set_parameters.py`. However it failed at `rcl_interfaces/msg/_parameter.py` this time:

```
  File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rcl_interfaces/msg/_parameter.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.value = kwargs.get('value', ParameterValue())
  File "/opt/ros/dashing/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rcl_interfaces/msg/_parameter.py", line 149, in value
    "The 'value' field must be a sub message of type 'ParameterValue'"
AssertionError: The 'value' field must be a sub message of type 'ParameterValue'
```

Then I kept trying, used `ParameterValue`, like this:

```
Parameter(name='parameter_1', value=ParameterValue(integer_value=3))
```

It did **not** cause any error, but when I check the param, it shows `Parameter not set.`. I am confused. The parameter `parameter_1` seems to be undeclared.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343322/%5Bros2%5D%5Brclpy%5D-how-to-set-parameter-hosted-by-another-node-via-service/) by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-02-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're very close. As there is currently no helper in rclpy, the "easier" might be to use only `rcl_interfaces` type for now to avoid confusion

> The 'parameters' field must be a set or sequence and each value of type 'Parameter'

This means that you need to pass a `rcl_interfaces.msg.Parameter` to this function.

> Then I kept trying, used ParameterValue, like this:

That's the way to go. On top of defining the value, the type of the parameter needs to be set, as it is not detected automatically

```
Parameter(name='parameter_1', value=ParameterValue(integer_value=3, type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_INTEGER))
```

The `send_request` function will look like this:

```
def send_request(self):
    new_param_value = ParameterValue(type=ParameterType.PARAMETER_INTEGER, integer_value=13)
    self.req.parameters = [Parameter(name='parameter_1', value=new_param_value)]
    self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)
```

Note that you'll need to import `ParameterType` from rcl_interfaces.msg at the top of your file.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2020-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lin404](https://answers.ros.org/users/50033/lin404/) on 2020-02-05**:
@marguedas Thank you very much! I have confirmed it, it works perfect!

**Comment by [dgarcialopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/52017/dgarcialopez/) on 2021-05-23**:
Does it work in foxy? I tried and get an error:

```
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/parameter.py", line 127, in __init__
type_ = Parameter.Type.from_parameter_value(value)
  File "/opt/ros/foxy/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rclpy/parameter.py", line 70, in from_parameter_value
    raise TypeError('The given value is not one of the allowed types.')
TypeError: The given value is not one of the allowed types.
```

**Comment by [Lothea](https://answers.ros.org/users/85387/lothea/) on 2021-10-19**:
It effectively works on foxy. I encountered the same issue and the problem was that my Parameter class was not imported from rcl_interface.msg. It shouldn't come from rclpy.parameter like the code above.

**Comment by [808brick](https://answers.ros.org/users/51297/808brick/) on 2022-05-05**:
It's worth noting the rclpy `Parameter` object has a `to_parameter_msg()` method to it so you do not need to explicitly import `rcl_interfaces.msg.Parameter` or `rcl_interfaces.msg.ParameterValue`

Example usage:

```
from rclpy.parameter import Parameter

...

def send_request(self):
    self.req.parameters = [Parameter(name='parameter_1', value=new_param_value).to_parameter_msg()]
    self.future = self.cli.call_async(self.req)
```

This is also nice as it will handle the type for you automatically and put the value in the correct message field without you having to manually specify things such as "integer_value" or "string_value" etc.